# How do I port php's openssl_sign to C#?

Tags: c#, php

I need to translate the following code to C# from php. What libraries / namespaces do I need to use?

```
function sign($method, $uuid, $data) {
    $merchant_private_key = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents('merchant_private_key.pem'));
    $plaintext = $method . $uuid . serialize_data($data);
    **openssl_sign($plaintext, $signature, $merchant_private_key);**
    return base64_encode($signature);
}
```

The api can be found over at http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php. Where do I start? I have no idea what the open_ssl sign in php does behind the covers.

Anyone able to help out that knows both php and C# or could someone at least explain what openssl_sign does in the background so that I can port it.

**EDIT: 2010-08-18** I can't find a way to use openssl, it keeps saying it can't load managedopenssl.dll. Think it is because of my machine being x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions.

I have found a solution for my problems. There is a library called [ChilKat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/rsa-dotnet.asp) that we will be using. The answer was found [here](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/08/openssl-and-rsacryptoserviceprovider.html). Unfortunately this does not work on my x64 machine. Fortunately our servers are all x86 still so we have some more time to look into a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here consist in reading and decoding the private key. You could use the [following openssl helper class](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/opensslkey.cs). Once you have referenced it you may try this:

```
public static string Sign(string method, string uuid, string data)
{
    string merchantPrivateKey = File.ReadAllText("merchant_private_key.pem");
    byte[] der = opensslkey.DecodePkcs8PrivateKey(merchantPrivateKey);
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = opensslkey.DecodePrivateKeyInfo(der))
    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        // This will contain the data to sign
        byte[] dataToSign = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(method + uuid + data);
        byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(dataToSign, md5);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }
}
```

In this example I have used MD5 but you could use anything that is appropriate to your scenario. I think [openssl_sign](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) uses SHA1 by default.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately I get problems with openssl I think it has to do with my machine being x64. Can't find any openssl.net for x64 either.

Comment: @CatZ: You can force the application to run in 32-bit mode through the compile options.  That should allow it to run 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: @CatZ: Alternately, there are Win64 builds of OpenSSL on this page: http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Yup, that's where desco's link took me.