# How to do openssl_sign using C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, private-key, php-openssl

How to do the following in C#.net? This example is in PHP,

```
 ​$Result ​= openssl_sign(​$data​, ​$signature​, ​$private_key​, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)​;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I port php's openssl\_sign to C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456922/how-do-i-port-phps-openssl-sign-to-c)

Comment: You can impliment SHA 256 using following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=net-5.0