# How can I get PHP to sign an input exactly the same as C#?

Tags: c#, php, signing

I'm working with an older API that requires XMLs to be signed. There is no proper documentation and the only code example was given in C#. I need to port this example to PHP. However, the code I've written in PHP gets a different output even when provided with the same input, causing the API call to fail.

I've narrowed it to this function in C#:

```
public byte[] CreateSignature(byte[] hash)
{
    RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter signatureFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(pfxCert.PrivateKey);
    signatureFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
    return signatureFormatter.CreateSignature(hash);
}
```

Here's the same operation in PHP:

```
public function createSignature($hashByteArray, $certArray) {
    $hash = implode(array_map("chr", $hashByteArray));
    $hashEncoded = base64_encode($hash);
    openssl_sign($hashEncoded,$signature, $certArray);
    return unpack("C*", $signature);
}
```

Note, the input  in openssl_sign can't take a byte array, so this is a possible point of difference. I've tried all algorithms provided by openssl_get_md_methods() and also phpseclib, neither have matched the output.

I've created a GitHub gist of the same example input and certificate in both [C#](https://gist.github.com/jjekson/28251f08d69a549f9276b425b5a6bcec) and [PHP](https://gist.github.com/jjekson/aa607125c6ac9769c58e677b408263d2) to better illustrate the issue.

***How can I get the same signing output in PHP as C#, given the same input?***

Comment: A major difference is, that you in PHP base64_encode() the data to be signed.

Comment: As Markus pointed out, you are using a different algorithm in PHP. The C# solution is setting the algorithm as "SHA1", have you tried using [`sha1`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1) as opposed to `base64_encode`?

Comment: The method used in C# does not work exactly like what openssl does. I've stored the keys into files, also the binary hash. PHP and openssl work exactly the same. Look at [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456922/how-do-i-port-phps-openssl-sign-to-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference between them.

The [RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter.CreateSignature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1signatureformatter.createsignature) method expects **a data hash**. `openssl_sign` on the other hand expects **the data itself**.

> From [PHP: openssl_sign - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php#refsect1-function.openssl-sign-description)
>
> openssl_sign() computes a signature for the specified data by
> generating a cryptographic digital signature using the private key
> associated with priv_key_id. **Note that the data itself is not
> encrypted.**

Apparently you generate a hash of some data to use with the API written in C#. Do not do it with `openssl_sign`, instead call with the original data. `openssl_sign` will hash it before signing, this is by design.